# How do I get this text inside of this HTML using Selenium Webdriver?

Tags: html, selenium, xpath, highcharts

I am attempting to retrieve this text
== *"1532.6788418669355"*
from this html. However, nothing that I try seems to work.
Here is what I attempted:

1. **IList options = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath(".//span//*"));**
   Options[0].Text = ""
   There are no other useful properties here
2. **Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//b"));**
   No text here as well and only 1 item returned
3. **Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='highcharts-tooltip']/span"))**
   Count = 1
   No text in this element either

```html
<div class="highcharts-tooltip" style="position: absolute; left: 83px; top: 15px; visibility: hidden;">
  <span id="ext-gen1350" style="position: absolute; white-space: nowrap; font-family: " Lucida Grande ","Lucida Sans Unicode
  ",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size: 12px; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; left: 8px; top: 8px;" zindex="1">
<span style="color:#000000">Index</span>
  <br/>
  <b>< 600</b>
  1532.6788418669355
  </span>
</div>
```

Here are the other things that I tried after getting some feedback. All of these either return empty or element not found exception:

```
var options = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@class='highcharts-tooltip']//following::span"));

var x = Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".highcharts-tooltip")).GetAttribute("textContent");

//var y = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='highcharts-tooltip']//b")).GetAttribute("textContent");

var z = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='highcharts-tooltip']//span")).GetAttribute("textContent");

z = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='highcharts-tooltip']/span")).GetAttribute("textContent");

z = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='highcharts-tooltip']/span")).GetAttribute("text");

**var a = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='highcharts-tooltip']/span/text()"));** this xpath works in Firebug perfectly, but not using Webdriver...

//var b = Driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@class='highcharts-tooltip']/span/text()"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because the WebElement you are trying to access is hidden, the `getText()` method returns an empty String.

Also the text you are trying to retrieve does not have an ID or tag, hence we have to retrieve the text of the parent.

```
Driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".highcharts-tooltip")).GetAttribute("textContent");
```

Will give you,

```
Index

  < 600
  1532.6788418669355
```

You need to retrieve your value from above.

Comment: GetAttribute("textContent");. Worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

Ok so first of all,

1. HTML you have shared has visibility:hidden so you wont be able to see it on the browser
2. span id : looks auto generated by extjs framework so you should not be using it, otherwise it will break in the next run.
3. try this in google chrome console. 
   $x("//div[@class='highcharts-tooltip']//following::span/text()")[3]

it works but surprisingly return 5 text element, haven't tried using selenium. 
just do this.

driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[@class='highcharts-tooltip']//following::span").getText() and try.

Hope this will help, let me know if works.

Thanks,
Manish Bansal
http://www.softtechlabs.com/blog

Comment: thanks for you help! However, this did not work for me as as C# doesn't have a getText() method. and using .Text got me "".